# Injecting PlatformTransactionManager into Ehcache

Tags: java, spring, ehcache

I am trying to inject Spring's `PlatformTransactionManager` into Ehcache, based on the documentation [here](http://ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/apis/transactions#configuration). My existing transaction manager is defined as follows:

```
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {

    JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    jpaTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);

    return jpaTransactionManager;
}
```

The documentation states that you need to write your own class that implements `TransactionManagerLookup`:

```
public class MyTransactionManagerLookup implements TransactionManagerLookup {

    @Override
    public TransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void register(EhcacheXAResource arg0, boolean arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void setProperties(Properties arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void unregister(EhcacheXAResource arg0, boolean arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

I've tried autowiring `PlatformTransactionManager` into `MyTransactionManagerLookup` but you cannot convert from PlatformTransactionManager to TransactionManager:

```
@Autowired
PlatformTransactionManager ptm;

@Override
public TransactionManager getTransactionManager() {

    return ptm; // cannot convert from PlatformTransactionManager to TransactionManager
}
```

I think I'm missing something obvious here and would really appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a [`JtaTransactionManager`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/transaction/jta/JtaTransactionManager.html) and pass to Ehcache the result of `JtaTransactionManager.getTransactionManager()`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Louis Jacomet's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28499905/3850156) I realised that I needed to use `JtaTransactionManager` instead of `JpaTransactionManager`.

I opted for [Atomikos](http://www.atomikos.com/) because Ehcache automatically recognises this transaction manager and registers it without the need for a custom `TransactionManagerLookup`.